# separate string from input selected value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two separate string value from the selected dropdown value. 
Like

```
<label>Book ID</label><span class="required">*</span>
<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" name="sel_Book">
    @foreach ($books as $data)                                       
        <option value="{{ $data->BookID }}-{{ $data->BookUnitPrice }}">{{ $data->BookName }} --- {{ $data->BookUnitPrice }}</option>                                                      
    @endforeach
</select>
```

So in the controller, the value is retrieved as `BookID-BookUnitPrice` eg `Eng11-500`" from `sel_Bookdropdown. So I have to separate this value and set`
Book = Eng11`and`UnitPrice = 500`. How can I do it?

code block

```
$booksout -> Distributor = $request->input('sel_Distributor');
$booksout -> Book = $request->input('sel_Book');
return response()->json($request); 
$booksout -> UnitPrice =
$booksout -> Quantity = $request->input('DistQuantity');
```

Comment: So if I post `Eng11-0` I can get a book for free?

Comment: @apokryfos No how can I prevent it

Comment: As an answer has already pointed out, the price is in your database so you can look it up based on the ID only so you don't really need to post the price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why you use ID's.

format your selects like:

```
<option value="{{ $data->BookID }}">
     {{ $data->BookName }} --- {{ $data->BookUnitPrice }}
</option>
```

Then in your controller when you fetch them:

The below code assumes the booksout model has all string/numeric fields:

```
$book_id = $request->input('sel_Book');
$book = Book::find($book_id);
if($book) {
   $booksout->Distributor = $book->Distributor->Name;
   $booksout->book = $book->BookName ;
   $booksout->UnitPrice = $book->BookUnitPrice
   $booksout->Quantity = $request->input('DistQuantity');
}
```

This way you can work with the complete book object, without having to worry that a user faked the data that's sent to your server. If you would depend on the price from the post/get request, I could buy your books for 0 by spoofing the price.

Never trust user data. Always try to gather as much as input as possible from your own trusted sources of data, where users can only supply product id and quantity.

Another note, consider working in camelCase instead of StudlyCase. so instead of `$book->BookUnitPrice` use `$book->bookUnitPrice` StudlyCase is usually interpreted for classnames by most programmers.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How can I set the value now for `BookUnitPrice`?

Comment: @nischalinn I added some example code, without knowing your exact model layout this is my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

simply send it as json payload

```
    <option value="{{ 
    json_encode([
               'book'=>$data->BookID, 
               'unitPrice' => $data->BookUnitPrice 
               ]}}">
   {{ $data->BookName }} --- {{ $data->BookUnitPrice }}</option>
```

so when you get it in the backend you do `json_decode($request->input('sel_Book'))` which will output :

```
[  
   book=> someid, 
   unitPrice => someprice
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. If you are using ajax for posting the data to server, in that case use 2 `data-attribute` and pass different value in it and you can easily get these values by using `.attr()` or `data()`.
2. If you are using form submit, in that case separate the value by using a unique separator like `:` or `^` and on the server side split the value and get the two individual components.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use assign Book id to value.But if you are not able to use that you can use explode function to split values you received in the controller.

```
$array = explode("-",$request->input('sel_Book'));
$book_id = $array[0];
$price = $array[1];
```